# Why must a function with a single parameter value must have default values specified for each parameter afterwards?

Tags: c++, syntax

For example:

```
void DoSome(int a = 10, int b = 10 ) {
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}
```

works. But

```
void DoSome(int a = 10, int b ) {
  std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}
```

will not.

Comment: How should the compiler distinguish the signatures by parameter positions otherwise? C++ has no notion of _named parameters_, it's only the positions and types that count for disambiguate function signatures.

Comment: you cannot have non-default parameters following default parameters

Comment: @bolov: I think that's the entire point of the question. *Why* can't you have that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your particular example may work, but consider a more general case:

```
void foo(int = 10, int, int = 20);
```

Now what does `foo(1, 2)` mean? It could be either `foo(10, 1, 2)` or `foo(1, 2, 20)`. This is confusing, and allowing this would hardly add convenience compared to the massive mental burden of figuring out what the actual arguments are.

Comment: Thanks for your example. Put another way, the restriction is for clarity.

Comment: @MarsPlus: Not really. It's not a "restriction" as it stands. If you wanted to allow arbitrary defaulted parameters, you would need an entire new set of rules to describe how they work.

Comment: @MarsPlus A way to have kind of _named parameters_ is to communicate them via `std::map<>` or similar data structures, or even your own classes to provide them.